# Is $X_1=\mathbb{Z}\times(0,1)$ and $X_2=\mathbb{Q}\times [0,1]$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X_1=\mathbb{Z}\times(0,1)$ and $X_2=\mathbb{Q}\times [0,1]$, is $X_1$ and $X_2$ homeomorphic or not?

---

I want see from the property of compactness, connectedness. And it is obvious that they both are not compact and disconnected.

Comment: What are your ideas about the question? Please edit to let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion of $X_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}\times[0,1]$, which is not connected, and the completion of $X_2$ is $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$, which is connected.

This only proves $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not isometric. I apologize for the wrong proof but the answer cannot be deleted.

---

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are not homeomorphic, since $X_1$ is locally Euclidean (or locally connected), but $X_2$ is not.

Comment: The property of being complete is not preserved under homeomorphism. Why is the connectedness of the completion a homeomorphism invariant?

Comment: What do you mean by being complete is not preserved under homeomorphism? Can you give an example?

Comment: Consider the two spaces $(0,1)$, and $S^1 -\{p\}$ (i.e. a circle missing a point). These two spaces are homeomorphic, but their "completions" are $[0,1]$ and $S^1$ respectively, which are not homeomorphic. The concept of "completion" is well defined for metric spaces, but not for topological spaces, as this example shows. If an argument uses completions it could be proving that two metric spaces aren't isometric, but it can't rule out being homeomorphic as topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Connected components of $X_1$ are homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ which are not compact but connected components of $X_2$ are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ which are compact. Hence they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I think the connected components of $X_{1}$ are $\{i\}\times(0,1)$, but how do we argue that?

Comment: It is certainly connected and if $U$ is an open set such that $(i,x),(j,y)\in U$ with $i< j$, then $U=(U\cap\{(a,t)\mid a<(i+j)/2\})\cup(U\cap\{(a,t)\mid a>(i+j)/2\}$.